# How to add a special character in a UIPicker view of integers

Tags: swift

**Still Learning swift**

**What Im trying to do** is add a "°C" and "°F"
after an integer, I have a created and array of ints and gave them a specific range
that should be in the pickerView, I got the values to display Im just struggling with how I could get that "special char " to display after the integer

I was thinking of maybe creating a for loop and load in the the values like that and append the "°C" and "°F" using the unicode scalar.

I was wondering if anyone has any recommendations of how i could get this done ?

```
class tempConversionTabViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {
var celsius: [Int] = []
var fahrenheitTemps: [Int] = []
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
 
       fahrenheitTemps += -129...134
       celsius += -90...57
   // for fahrenheitTemps in -129...134{
    //    tempPicker.append
    //}
    
}



 func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}


   public func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    switch
        segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex{
    case 0:
        return fahrenheitTemps.count
    default:
        return celsius.count
    }
}


    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int , forComponent component: Int) -> String?{

switch segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0:
      var selected = fahrenheitTemps[tempPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]
                     selected = (selected - 32) * 5/9
                      
                     convertedLabel.text = String("\(selected) \u{2103}")
            
                let myString = fahrenheitTemps.map { String($0)}
            return myString[row]
    default:
    var selected = celsius[tempPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]
                   selected = (selected * 9/5) + 32
                          
                   convertedLabel.text = String("\(selected) \u{2109}")
               let myString = celsius.map { String($0)}
           return myString[row]
    }

}
```

[Image of how I want it to display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwFed.png)

Comment: Show the UIPickerViewDataSource and UIPickerViewDelegate methods

Comment: @matt Just updated it

Comment: Yup, as you've been told, now that you've shown the line `return myString[row]`, that's the place to append the extra material to the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use string concatenation to add the character:

Change:

```
return myString[row]
```

to:

```
return myString[row] + "\u{2109}"
```